# Batch script to unzip and delete compressed file

Tags: batch-file, unzip, delete-file

In batch scripting, how do I unzip a file and immediately delete the compressed version? I'm trying the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for /R "C:\Lazy\Wafer Run Requests" %%I in ("*.zip") do (

  "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpnI" "%%~fI" 
  Del %%I

)
```

Comment: Never mind, just changed Del %%I to Del "%%~fI" and it worked. Maybe someone can explain this?

Comment: add this to your loop:  echo %%I  echo %%~fl

Comment: You path\filename has spaces etc.  A simple `DEL "%%I"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Found this online:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ben/archive/2007/03/09/path-manipulation-in-a-batch-file.aspx

Path Manipulation in a Batch File

```
Have you ever typed "help for" at a command line? If you write a lot of batch files, read through it and you'll probably save yourself some time. Today I was trying to figure out how to get just the filename out of a path that may or may not contain the fully qualified filename. All I had to do was "%~nx1". Brilliant! Here are a few more nifty variable modifiers from the help docs:

%~I - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI - expands %I to a path only
%~nI - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI - expands %I to size of file
%~$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH environment variable and expands %I to the fully qualified name of the first one found. If the environment variable name is not
defined or the file is not found by the search, then this modifier expands to the empty string
The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
%~dpI - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
%~nxI - expands %I to a file name and extension only
%~fsI - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
%~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH environment variable for %I and expands to the drive letter and path of the first one found.
%~ftzaI - expands %I to a DIR like output line


set basedir=%~1%   - removes the quotes from the first variable passed in
```

Answer (score 0):

run this

```
powershell Expand-Archive file_to_unzip_path.zip where_to_put_the_unziped_file
del file_path_you_want_to_delete
```

it does not delete the compressed version emediatly though, it waits to unzip the file first, otherwise it would break. also, it doesn't require any addition software as windows has it built in.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me.
I do the deletion in a second moment due to the release of the file by the program

REM  Unzip

FOR /r %%J IN (*.zip) DO ("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%J" "-o%%~pJ" -y)

REM Deleting

FOR /r %%L IN (*.zip) DO (ATTRIB -h -r -s "%%L"|DEL "%%L")

Or
FOR /r %%L IN (*.zip) DO (DEL "%%L")